# Does a callback exist for "chrome.storage.local.set"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to send back a Chrome message only after the chrome.storage.local has been set, but I cannot find a way to "import" the `sendResponse` function inside it.

Please consider that all this code is being executed into a **background script** and **triggered by a message** sent from a content_script and/or from the browser action popup. So this is why I need to send the response back.

Do you have any idea?

```
// Global array
let documents = [];

// Recursive ajax call
function get_and_merge_data(cursor = null, token, sendResponse) {
    //console.log("Data collection started");
    let url = (cursor) ? `https://[omissis]?[omissis]cursor=?{cursor}` : `[omissis]?paging_mode=standard_cursor`;
    //console.log("Cursor: " + cursor);

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            "X-AUTH-TOKEN": token
        },
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: url,
        // dataType: "json",
        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
            // Silence is golden...
        }
    }).done(function (response) {

        chrome.storage.local.set({ "documents_cache": response }, function (sendResponse) {
            console.log(`documents_cache has been saved`);
            documents = new Array(); // Empty the array

            sendResponse("documents have been loaded and saved!"); // <-- this does not work
        });
        //return
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback signature for [`chrome.storage.local.set`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-set) is:

```
function() {...};
```

Yet you're passing it:

```
        function (sendResponse) {
            console.log(`documents_cache has been saved`);
            documents = new Array(); // Empty the array

            sendResponse("documents have been loaded and saved!"); // <-- this does not work
        }
```

The `sendResponse` variable defined in the above callback is going to be `undefined`, and it will overwrite the original `sendResponse` which was originally declared here:

```
// Recursive ajax call
function get_and_merge_data(cursor = null, token, sendResponse) {
```

All this to say, simply change your callback to `.set` to take no arguments:

```
        function () {
            console.log(`documents_cache has been saved`);
            documents = new Array(); // Empty the array

            sendResponse("documents have been loaded and saved!"); // <-- this does not work
        }
```